# Checkbox padding not working on Sony Erricsson XPERIA Neo V MT11i device

Tags: android, checkbox

I want to display check boxes with image background. when ever i am assigning my image to Checkbox button. it is showing irrelevant space between check box and text.

so I tried it with paddingLeft that removes space between checkbox and text on SAMSUNG S2,
Galaxy ACE and  Tablets. But it is not affecting for **Sony Erricsson XPERIA Neo V MT11i device**

> ```
>  <CheckBox
>         android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:button="@drawable/checkbox_background"
>         android:paddingLeft="14dp"
>         android:text="@string/email_copy"
>         android:textColor="#39b54a"
>         android:textSize="11sp" />
> ```

Please help me out of this issue